# Firebase v9.8.4 deleteDoc Not Deleting from db

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of Posts that are added to my db via this method:

```
const sendPost = async (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (loading) return;
        setLoading(true);
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "Posts"), {
            id: tokenId,
            postId: UID,
            username: username,
            profilePic: uri,
            bio: bio,
            likes: 0,
            text: input,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
      });
```

I have created a delete button with an onClick handler with the following code:

```
 const handleDelete = async (e:any) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    deleteDoc(doc(db, "Posts", post.postId));
    console.log(post.postId);
  }
```

The console.log in the above code matches the UID of the Document that im trying to delete, but nothing happens. Note: I added delete to the rules, and still no luck.

Does anybody know if I'm missing a step or can point me in the right direction??
[Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAdcC.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just don't know what is doc ID. Using `addDoc(collection(db, "Posts"), data)` function, you generate random document ID, and it is not an UID! To get that ID, you need to show how you get data from Firebase.

Using `getDocs` function, you can get doc ID like this:

```js
async function getDocuments() {
  const ref = collection(db, 'Posts')
  const result = await getDocs(ref)
  let data = []
  if(result.exists()) {
    result.foreach(docSnap => {
      const doc = docSnap.data()
      doc.docID = docSnap.id // here you getting real document ID
      data.push(doc)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**You have document ID above `+ Start Collection` blue button, not in `postID` field!**

Comment: I now have all of the Document ID's of my posts logged. How would I delete just 1 post based off of the Posts UID?